# getting incorrect JSON from object array in response entity returned by API

Tags: java, json, spring

I have some object array as follows:

```
Object[] userObj = new Object[] {"userName: "+user, 
                      "userId: "+id, "userCategory: "+category};
```

I am trying to get the following JSON from my Object :

```
  {
    "fault": {
        "userName": "Test User",
        "userObj": [{
            "userId": "1"
        }, {
            "userCategory": "general"
        }]
    }
}
```

But what I get is the following:

```
{
    "fault": {
        "userName: Test User",
        "userObj": [{
            "userId: 1"
        }, {
            "userCategory: general"
        }]
    }
}
```

Is there any easy way to put double quotes between key values in JSON separated by colon?

Comment: "But what I get is the following:" How do you get that, please post relevant code?

Comment: I am using ResponseEntity of Spring Framework and having some conversion classes in the rest of the code. The point is - Object that I use needs to be changed in a way to give correct JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
Object[] userObj = new Object[2];
        userObj[0] = Collections.singletonMap("userName", user);
        userObj[1] = Collections.singletonMap("userCategory", category);
```